# Github -> Azure deploy dll used by another process

Tags: azure, entity-framework-5, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment, azure-git-deployment

Unfortunately, due to issues with Azure's lack of EF 5 spatial support, I need to include the relevant DLL myself: [related link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazurewebsitespreview/thread/6f68a726-bddb-4312-ae75-043b775da271/)

Once I included the SqlServerSpatial.dll I was able to complete successfully deploy by using the Publish tool inside of Visual Studio.

However, when I try to use the Github -> Azure deployment with the relevant DLLs being available in the github repro, the deployment fails with the message:

```
The process cannot access the file 'C:\DWASFiles\Sites\<my app name>\VirtualDirectory0
\site\wwwroot\bin\SqlServerSpatial.dll' because it is being used by another process.
```

I'm not really sure how to troubleshoot from here and could use some help. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you restart the website from the dashboard before deploying? Does that unlock the file?

Comment: I'm getting the same error in the following directory: C:\DWASFiles\Sites\<my app>\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\App_Data\Dependencies\

Comment: Hrmm, if I restart from the dashboard and then retry the failed deploy - that gets me past the failure. Not sure yet how to skip the failure completely.

Comment: This question shouldn't be a problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

use nuget package manager instead of adding the dll and pushing dlls using git.

PM> `Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types`

Ignore the bin folder from git by adding bin/ in .gitignore  file

usually adding dlls in source control causing issues and its not a good behavior.

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't possible when this question was written. There was a bug that has since been fixed, so I don't think the question is valid anymore.